# objective-c OSX class inheritance

Tags: objective-c

I have a method “ShowPop:nil” in a “Navigation” class - it displays a popover.

I have inherited the Navigation class from the AppDelegate.h. When I call [Self ShowPop:nill] from AppDelegate.m the popover wont pop but the method does run.

Note, I know the popover method works because it pops perfectly from a IB button connection from the same method.

Sample code below.

```
@interface Navigation_Main : NSObject
{
}
    @property (weak) IBOutlet NSPopover *popover_AddStuff;
    - (IBAction)ShowPop:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)ShowPop:(id)sender;
{
    [_popover_AddStuff showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
}
```

.

```
**#import "Navigation_Main.h"**
@interface AppDelegate : Navigation_Main <NSApplicationDelegate,NSTextFieldDelegate>
{
    - (IBAction)showPopup:(id)sender;
}

- (IBAction)showPopup:(id)sender {
    //[self ShowPop:nil]; ---No pop
    [super ShowPop:nil];  ---No pop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSPopover throws an exception when the positioning view is nil, and (as a consequence) won't show the popover. Ensure you pass a view for the popover to be shown relative to, not nil.